# Regex Search Error

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a bit new with mongo node and express and I'm experiencing some problems. I'm trying to query all products in a db based on certain keywords. Ideally, I want to find one product containing words from a user search and defaulting to a fixed product if none of the words are found to be contained in a collection

Here's my schema setup:

```
var  express  = require("express"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose");

var productSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:  String,
    image: String,
    description:  String,
    keywords:  String,
});
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

My idea is to match users with a product based on their query. Even if they type a full sentence (currently it only works with single words). If there's no product, I want to default to one product in the db. Here's my route setup:

```
var express  = require("express"),
    Product  =require('../models/product'),
    router   = express.Router();

router.get('/myroute', function(req,res){
// if there's a query
    if(req.query.search){
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi'); 
    var regexSearch = {
        "keywords": {
                "$regex": regex
          }
    };
    Product.findOne(regexSearch, function(err, foundProduct){
        if(err){
            console.log('product not found');
        } else{
            res.render('show', {product: foundProduct});
              }
    });

    } else{
          Product.findOne({name: 'defaultP'}, function(err, foundProduct){        
              if(err){
                  console.log(err);
              } else{
                  res.render('show', {product: foundProduct});
              }
          });

      }  

  });

function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

module.exports = router;
```

Currently everything works fine when I search a keyword that exists (But not a sentence). However, if I search for a sentence or a keyword that's not present in the db, I get an error when rendering:

> Cannot read property 'name' of null
>       at eval (eval at  (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), :22:33)
>       at returnedFn (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:555:17)
>       at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:203:34)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:412:10)
>       at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/match.js:20:23
>       at Query. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3755:16)
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:277:21
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)

Comment: The error is produced because you simply do not check to see if the result of `.findOne()` actually returned something. When it does not then it is `null` and you don't check but just blindly send it to the template. I suspect the reason for no result is the "mangling" of the string being done with the `.replace()`. Not sure what you are intending to do there, but the output to me would seem unlikely to match any "sentence" stored in the database.

Comment: Hey Neil. I know this is the reason....just confused on how to check the result before sending it to the template. I want to send the product found to the template...if the search terms didn't match to any product then I want to find mydefault product from the db and load it to the template...

Comment: `if (foundProduct != null)` and your `else` returns a "not found" response. Like I said though the `.replace()` here makes no sense since it's just appending `\\` to the end of each word, and I doubt your data is stored like that.

Comment: Omg I'm so stupid. I'll be right back. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Hey Neil, that was the issue. I was just sending whatever I got to the template. When it was null then I got the error. Thanks a bunch. Does SO have chatrooms?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and then put your function escapeRegex inside RegExp.

```
var regExpr = new RegExp(".*" + req.query.search + ".*", "i");
var regexSearch = {
    "keywords": regExpr
};
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow this, it may helpful to you.

```
var str = "";
var searchResult = "";

str = new RegExp(".*" + req.query.search + ".*", "i");

searchResult = { "keywords": str };
```